# Removing empty array values on multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I want to remove arrays cctype, cctypologycode, and amount when they are empty from array. best way to do it ?

```
{
  "ccInput": [
    {
      "designSummaryId": 6,
      "CCType": "A",
      "CCTypologyCode": "A",
      "Amount": "1"
    },
    {
      "designSummaryId": 7,
      "CCType": "",
      "CCTypologyCode": "",
      "Amount": ""
    },
  ]
}
```

`ccInput[1]` should be removed from the array

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove some objects from your array, use [Array.prototytpe.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

You can do it in an **immutable way** by copying each property of your object using the spread operator and then filter the `ccInput` property:

```js
const obj = {ccInput:[{designSummaryId:6,CCType:"A",CCTypologyCode:"A",Amount:"1"},{designSummaryId:7,CCType:"",CCTypologyCode:"",Amount:""}]};

const result = { ...obj, ccInput: obj.ccInput.filter(x => x.CCType && x.CCTypologyCode) };

console.log(result);
```

Or if you want to modify your object in place, simply reassign the `ccInput` property:

```js
const obj = {ccInput:[{designSummaryId:6,CCType:"A",CCTypologyCode:"A",Amount:"1"},{designSummaryId:7,CCType:"",CCTypologyCode:"",Amount:""}]};

obj.ccInput = obj.ccInput.filter(x => x.CCType && x.CCTypologyCode);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about TypeScript, but I do know you can set the array to `[]`. However, for those of you looking to get rid of only *part* of an array but not *all* of it, the simplest way to do so *that I know of* is to just set each value to `0` for numbers, `''` for characters, `""` for Strings, etc.